# Testing for randomness in a number list

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a list of numbers ranging between 0 - 9. The list has 1 million of these numbers. I am trying to test if these numbers are random or there is a hidden existing pattern of sorts. After obtaining results, I am using Chi Squared Test to determine if the values are random.

Tests already done:

**Count**

1. Count how many times each number has repeated. (ie: 0: 100000 times , 1: 99868 times ...)

**Gaps**

2. Check for gap between a repeat of a number. (example: Number 0 - 07860 has gap of 3 before 0 repeats again. So count gaps for 0 - gap 2: 12647 times, gap 3: 4500 times.....)

**Serial**

3. Check for serial pattern. Patterns for 2,3,4 all the way to 30. (example pattern 3 For these numbers - 7856743 : check pattern 785, 856, 567.....)

**Poker**

4. Check for poker pattern. Patterns 2,3,4 all the way to 30. (example pattern 71188 which has 5 numbers. Check how often this pattern repeats. For example in 7118828374571188273462371188 this pattern repeated 3 times.

I wrote the above tests in Java. Is there any other checks I can do no matter how small the significance could be. Been looking up books and I am not able to find any further advanced tests for randomness.

Please advice.

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: Might be a question for mathmaticians, not programmers.

Comment: @STF what are you going to derive from the OP's code? The question is not related to code. That might mean it's off-topic here, but that's a whole different story.

Answer (score 1):

NIST has published a bunch of tests for random number generators. They are not implemented in Java, so if that rules out using their test suite you might use them to draw inspiration from.

http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/rng/stats_tests.html

Answers to [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/394/what-tests-can-i-do-to-ensure-my-prng-is-working-correctly) question also has some relevant links and answers.